# Binding image horizontally

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 app.

I am trying to databind a few images into the ListBox, but it is showing in vertical:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="picList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding picture}" Height="80" Width="80"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You should set the ItemsPanel for the ListBox as StackPanel with Horizontal orientation. It will be responsible for the Items arrangement in the ListBox.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```